# Render HTML file with CSS and local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following content in an HTML file placed under `public/company/` with a CSS file `css/style.css`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">Name {name}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to render this HTML file with the CSS stylesheet from an action and replace `{name}` without changing the physical file content and place. I can render the HTML file but the CSS file would not be found. Can anyone help me render the HTML file with the CSS file and replace the `{name}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click here](http://www.morshed-alam.com/2012/12/render-html-file-in-rails-using-nokogiri.html) to see an article the way you can do that. Hope it will help!

But, I'm not sure why you are looking to render that way where Rails has all the features in place.

Answer (score 1):

`css/style.css` when called from `company/file.html` will try to load `company/css/style.css`.

Comment: The css file is located under company/css/style.css

Comment: It's matter how you rendered the file from rails action. System will look in to {views}/css/style.css if you render using render :file => "...." but your purpose will not meet

Comment: @ Morshed Alam - you are right. @ Amadan - file is located under public/company/css/style.css and my requirement is to render the file from rails action with design(css file)

Comment: Then I don't understand the question... If you're rendering from the template, why wouldn't you want it to be in the views directory, and why aren't you using a controller, and why do you invent your own templating system when so many good ones exist already?

Comment: +1 @Amadan. I think you hit the real question on the head. Why reinvent the wheel and do things that do not conform to the Rails way? Rails is powerful and has all the features in place, and doing things in a contrary fashion is a major effort, wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSS file is located at `/public/company/css/style.css`, then your static HTML file should link it with an absolute path. Use a leading `/` in the resource's path indicate an absolute path.:

```
<link href="/company/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Note that the Rails router will likely catch this request and raise an exception. Depending on the web server, you may need to enable static assets or serve directly, bypassing Rails altogether.

Changing the content of a static HTML file server-side without actually modifying it (ie. adding ERb) isn't straightforward. You could:

- inject some javascript into the response to perform modifications client-side. (ugly)
- load the static HTML file using Nokogiri, et. al., modify the content, and send the output to the client. (expensive)

Sounds to me like these vanilla HTML/CSS files are third party (designer? client?) and you would like to drop it in `/public` and have it work automatically with Rails. That would be nice, but it's not that easy. You'd be better off using Rails' built-in templating system, but that means modifying files and moving them to the expected locations.